# How to correctly use ellipsis in nested function

Tags: r, parent-child, ellipsis

See `edit`first

I have a parent function and a child function. I would like to use `...` feature in my child function. Specifically I am wondering how I can correctly use `...` in these specific rows of code in my child function:

```
function(theList,...){

  ####
  CombinedList=lapply(seq_along(theList), function (x,...) {

    .x <-  as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1]

    elementz=data.frame(rbind(.x[1][[x]],.x[2][[x]],.x[3][[x]]))
```

The `...` is supposed to be a list of lists, i.e. each element of `...` list is a list.
In my main (master) function, below, the `...` would contain `SharpList` and `SortinoList`.

```
windowSize=36

    PerformanceDF  <- function(data,windowSize,AvgForvalt=(0.02/12)){
      require(quantmod,quietly = TRUE)
      require(reshape2,quietly = TRUE)
      require(PerformanceAnalytics,quietly = TRUE)
      require(xts,quietly = TRUE)

      #36 mån rolling window list

      windows <- embed(1:nrow(data), windowSize)

      lapplyApproach <- function(data, windows) {  
        windowsList <- split(t(windows), rep(1:nrow(windows), each=ncol(windows)))  
        names(windowsList) <- unlist(lapply(windowsList,
                                            function(x) data[x[1],1]))
        return(lapply(windowsList,function(x) data[rev(x),]))
      }


      DropBench=grep("Benchmark",names(hedgesample),ignore.case=TRUE)
      data=data[,-c(DropBench)]

      theList=lapplyApproach(data,windows) 


      ##xts

      theListXts=lapply(theList,function(x){

        blab=xts(x[,-1],as.Date(x[,1])) 

        return(blab)

      })



      ##Sharpe Ratio     
      SharpList=lapply(theListXts,function(x) {

        hej=SharpeRatio(x,FUN="StdDev")

        rownames(hej)=NULL

        hej[is.infinite(hej)] <- 0

        return(hej)

      })

      ##Sortino ratio

      SortinoList=lapply(theListXts,function(x) {

        mmm=SortinoRatio(x)

        rownames(mmm)=NULL

        mmm[is.infinite(mmm)]<-0

        return(mmm)

      })




      function(theList,...){




      ####
      CombinedList=lapply(seq_along(theList), function (x,...) {

        .x <-  as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1]

        elementz=data.frame(rbind(.x[1][[x]],.x[2][[x]],.x[3][[x]]))

        rownames(elementz)=NULL

        elementz$Statistic=.x

        return(elementz)


      },...)

      names(CombinedList)=names(theList)

      return(CombinedList)}}
```

Right now I get the `error`

```
Error in .x[1][[x]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rbind(.x[1][[x]], .x[2][[x]]) :
  (symbol) object cannot be coerced to type 'list'
2: In rbind(.x[1][[x]], .x[2][[x]]) :
  (symbol) object cannot be coerced to type 'list'
3: In rbind(.x[1][[x]], .x[2][[x]]) :
  (symbol) object cannot be coerced to type 'list'
```

Best Regards!

`EDIT`

Found a solution:

```
function(theList,...){

  CombinedList=lapply(seq_along(theList), function (x,...) {

    .x <-  as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1]

    elementz=data.frame(rbind(eval(.x[[1]])[[x]],eval(.x[[2]])[[x]],eval(.x[[3]])[[x]]))
```

But does anyone have a nicer solution?

Comment: @fotNelton Well...Found the solution CombinedList=lapply(seq_along(theList), function (x,...) {
    
    .x <-  as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1]
    
    elementz=data.frame(rbind(eval(.x[[1]])[[x]],eval(.x[[2]])[[x]],eval(.x[[3]])[[x]]))
    
    rownames(elementz)=NULL
    
    elementz$Statistic=as.character(.x)
    
    return(elementz)
    
    
  },...)

Comment: Please post it as an answer not a comment.

Comment: It appears you only want attention of people who already use that combination of packages because you offer no specific test case.

Comment: The problem was in base, but thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function(theList,...){

  CombinedList=lapply(seq_along(theList), function (x,...) {

    .x <-  as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1]

    elementz=data.frame(rbind(eval(.x[[1]])[[x]],eval(.x[[2]])[[x]],eval(.x[[3]])[[x]]))
```